# My input code for LC-3 isn't working as intended

Tags: assembly, lc3

I've been working on this bit of code to take a string of input and to have it displayed after I hit the enter key, but it doesn't work for some reason and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong at all. I would love some help to figure this one out.

```
      LD  R1, RT
      LEA R2, ARRAY
INPUT GETC           ;read the input character 
      OUT            ;echoes the character
      ADD R3, R0, R1
      BRz ENDINPUT
      STR R0, R2, #0
      ADD R2, R2, #1
      BR  INPUT
ENDINPUT
      STR R3, R2, #0
      LEA R0, ARRAY         ;outputs the string of characters
      PUTS
```

Comment: Anyone can help with this? :s

Answer (score 1):

Late response, but in case it's still haunting you, hope these help!

- Check that the value in location `RT` is correct. If you are checking for a 'LF' when you hit 'Enter', R2 should have the value of negative 'LF'. In 2s-complement this is `0xFFFFFFF0`.
- Make sure your `ARRAY` is large enough to hold your inputs. Check your `.BLKW` line – I'm assuming you didn't post these lines in your post.